# Is the insulation on my water pipes asbestos?

Tags: plumbing, insulation, asbestos

I've tried to match this insulation with publicly searchable images of asbestos. It doesn't quite match up, so my hope is that the inspector was right, rather than the plumber.  The plumber believes it to be asbestos.  I'm planning to do a test, but it would be great if I can have some idea of the level of risk before ripping some off to test.

The home was built in 1950 and the material is wrapping some very old, galvanized steel pipes.

If anyone is able to reasonably suspect what the material actually is, it would be helpful.

[image: first picture]
[image: second picture]

Comment: Testing is the only way to be sure.  For removing a small piece for testing, eye protection and a mask should be all you need to be safe.  It is the working with it and breathing in of the fibres for usually a long time that is dangerous.  If it is asbestos, then the removing of it from the pipes will need more protections, removing the pipes without touching the wrap will need less.  The age and type does make it suspect.

Comment: Yes, the only way to be sure is to have tested. But I see another problem:  It looks like the copper pipe is directly connected to the galvanized steel pipe without dielectric fittings.  That well lead to electrolysis and eventual failure of the connections.

Comment: I believe there was some type of blue substance used between, but not a dielectric fitting.  Thank you for the tip.

Comment: It does look like asbestos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You CANNOT identify asbestos from visual inspection.  Some claim to be able to do so but they are just guessing based on past experience.  The problem is that there are many materials that can look like asbestos but in fact are not.  There are also asbestos-containing materials that look like non-asbestos products.  The ONLY way to tell is to have a sample tested by a lab.

Keep in mind, however, that asbestos is not cyanide or sarin gas.  It will not kill you with a single whiff.  That being said, try to minimize your exposure and avoid generating dust from the product.  Once you have a confirmed asbestos diagnosis, hire a licensed company to remove and dispose of it.

Your home inspection is another matter entirely.  Not all inspectors are as vigilant as they should be and it's quite possible he never even looked at it.  Yours would not be the first case where an inspector just checked the boxes and gave a clean bill of health without doing any actual inspection.

Answer (score 1):

The gurus here have said that the only way to know for sure is to get it tested at a reliable asbestos testing lab.

That said, it does look somewhat like pipe insulation that I saw at my former workplace, an old factory that once had steam heat. The powers that were at the factory said the insulation could have been asbestos.

Best not to disturb it until you get instructions from the lab.